# how to reduce the load in model hook in Ember

Tags: ember.js

I have a routes/paper.js file which has below model hook

```
model(params,transition){
   let user = store.getRequest('user','paper/user')
   let address = store.getRequest('address','paper/address')

return RSVP.hash({
   user,
   address
}).then((model) => {
    set(model, 'address_name', get(model.address, 'name'));

    return ...model
})

}
```

I want to reduce the load in model hook by moving the api request to controller and use it in setcontroller . but the model is not having the data , please find below my modification

//controller/paper.js

```
testerfunction(params){
 let user = store.getRequest('user','paper/user')
   let address = store.getRequest('address','paper/address')
   let paperId = params.paperID

return RSVP.hash({
paperID: paperID,
   user,
   address
}).then((model) => {
    set(model, 'address_name', get(model.address, 'name'));

    return ...model
})

}


//routes/paper.js 


model(params,transition){

}


setupController(controller,model) {
 testerfunction(get(this,'model.params');
}
```

but my page render is blank

Answer (score 1):

The default implementation of setupController is:

```
setupController(controller, model) {
  set(controller, 'model', model);
}
```

Therefore you have two options, you can call the default implementation using `_super`, or you can reimplement it. Also note that you need to make `params` part of the object returned from the `model` hook. Finally, your `testerfunction` returns a promise. While `model` expects you to return a promise, `setupController` does not.

```
model(params) {
  return { params };
}

setupController(controller, model) {
  return testerfunction(get(this, 'model.params')).then(resolvedModel => {
    this._super(controller, resolvedModel);
  });
}
```

For more information about `setupController`, see https://api.emberjs.com/ember/2.18/classes/Route/methods/setupController?anchor=setupController

I've written this answer to be compatible with Ember 2.x based on your code but please in the future let us know which version of Ember you are using.

Comment: Are you sure that an async `setupController` hook is supported? I'm especially concerned if it's officially supported to defer the call of `_super()`. As the routing stack is known to be a little bit fragile I would be worried about bugs.

Comment: I don't know about "officially supported". It does work.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using [ember-concurrency](http://ember-concurrency.com/docs/introduction/). Your Route would end up looking something like:

```
loadUser: task(function * () { return store.getRequest('user','paper/user') })
loadAddress: task(function * () { store.getRequest('address','paper/address') })
loadAddressName: task(function * (addressPromise) {
  const address = yield addressPromise
  return get(address, 'address_name')
})
model(params, transition) {
  const address = this.loadAddress.perform()
  const user = this.loadUser.perform()
  const address_name = this.loadAddressName.perform(address)
  return {
    user,
    address,
    paperID: params.paperID
  }
}
```

As an added bonus, you get a loading status for each one in your controller/template so you can do things like:

```
{{#unless model.user.isLoading}}
  {{model.user.name}}
{{else}}
  Some loading state
{{/unless}}
```

Another option would be to add a loading template that is rendered while the model hook is loading. You just have to add a template next to you main template called `your_template_name_loading.hbs`

Comment: still the api request is fired inside the model hook , how does this reduce the work of model hook()

Comment: I would assume you're interested in your model hook returning quickly, not exactly where the code is executed from, this way it will return almost immediately. This kind of code is exactly what the model hook is supposed to house. If all you want is for the code to be in the controller file instead of the route file, it's certainly possible but I'd have a think about why. I always try not to go against the framework authors' intentions unless I have a good reason.

Comment: If entering the route the template is not rendered before the model hook is resolved. So the `isLoading` property is useless in that case. Also the Ember Data Model has a [`isLoading` property](https://api.emberjs.com/ember-data/3.18/classes/Model/properties/isLoading?anchor=isLoading) itself. No need to introduce Ember Concurrency for this one.